# Django ALLOWED_HOSTS vs CORS(django-cors-headers)

Tags: python, django, django-cors-headers

What is the difference between ALLOWED_HOSTS and CORS. If I have defined ALLOWED_HOSTS do I need to define also CORS? I am not using django templates.
Also do I have the possibility to define those two dynamically?(I think not)
I am using django as backend, and multiple reactjs frontend apps on different hosts.

Comment: Please include more information. Are you building an API server? Is there going to be a static JavaScript that queries it? Will those be hosted on the host? Different host? Why do you think you need CORS?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve and what do you mean by define those two "dynamically"?

Comment: I have sort of affiliate program, where user can register their sites, so I don&amp;#39;t want to restart the server every time and change them manually, what I&amp;#39;m doing now, and take the url&amp;#39;s from databse every time an user become a affiliate

Comment: I see.. ALLOWED_HOSTS accepts wildcards as well, even though potentially that is going to make your application more vulnerable to attacks.. but that's something you would have to deal with given your business requirement

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Doc on [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).
In short, in production environment where you have `DEBUG=FALSE`, your Django application will not serve in a domain or subdomain that is not specified in ALLOWED_HOSTS. It's a whitelist of trusted domains you can **serve** your backend app on. In other words, these are the domains your backend app can be accessed from.

[CORS](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors) on the other hand stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. I'm assuming you are asking because you are also doing Django Rest Framework. CORS has nothing to do with which domain you serve your backend app on. Instead, it basically allows your frontend apps, like the multiple reactjs apps you mentioned, to interact with your APIs without having to deploy all of them on the same domain. [django-cors-header](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) is the recommended package for configuring CORS.

Comment: And if I have another backend which is making python requests to this backend, CORS will also allow/deny requests in this sittuation?

Comment: Sorry a little bit late here but actually that's not correct. CORS is important and essential to (and only applies to) requests sent from web browsers. If you're sending a request from a server you can ignore CORS policies and make any request you want.

Comment: @m0etaz, do you need to set both CORS and ALLOWED_HOSTS with web browser? or Can I ignore ALLOWED_HOSTS in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

#### In short

- [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) lets you specify the host/domain the backend/server can run on
- [CORS](https://ALLOWED_HOSTS) lets you define which frontend/client [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) are allowed to call your backend (apart from ones on the same scheme, domain, and port)

###### Note that:

- `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is useful to prevent [HTTP Host header attacks](https://portswigger.net/web-security/host-header)
- It is important to note that CORS **is only relevant for browsers**. Furthermore, these settings are only needed because of the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Other servers, scripts, and programs will still be able to call your API regardless.
- The main benefits of enabling CORS are for enabling restricted public APIs and allowing the browser to make [cross-origin "credentialed" requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#requests_with_credentials)