# Why does Django allow incoming connections not specified in ALLOWED_HOSTS?

Tags: django

Scenario -
Someone is requesting a url served by a Django app. His IP is 3.3.3.3 . It could be a client but could be a server too, I don't know at the time of the request.

In project settings file, there is

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"]
```

He (3.3.3.3) is still served. What are the allowed hosts for then?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS` specifies what *host* the server is allowed to act as, not which clients are allowed to make requests to it. The latter would be pretty crazy, as you'd usually need to whitelist basically the entirety of the internet in practice.

Comment: The whole explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228488/django-allowed-hosts-vs-corsdjango-cors-headers) .

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just an example would be - a web server is serving a domain and is to redirect the request to the django app. The app doesn't have the domain in ALLOWED_HOSTS and will therefore refuse to serve the request, is it right?

Comment: One physical machine can serve several different domains. Several DNS entries for different host names can point to the same server. `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com']` makes the server respond only to requests made to `example.com`. If the DNS entry for `foobar.com` also points to the same server, requests made to `foobar.com` will be rejected by the server.